# OpenGL/GLSL precision error

Tags: macos, opengl, macros, glsl

I have a simple vertex shader:

```
precision mediump float;

attribute vec4 position;

attribute vec4 color;
varying vec4 f_color;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 modelView;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = projection * modelView * position;
    f_color = color;
    f_texCoord = texCoord;
}
```

This fails to compile, stating (using getShaderInfoLog()):

```
ERROR: 0:1: 'precision' : syntax error syntax error
```

It compiles fine if i remove the line with the precision specifier.

System:

```
OS: Mac OX 10.9.2 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce 320M 256 MB
GLSL Ver.: 1.20
```

Someone help me out.

Comment: What the version of OpenGL and GLSL? The following qualifiers are deprecated as of GLSL 1.30 (OpenGL 3.0) and removed from GLSL 1.40 and above.

Comment: @SAKrisT I  I see __gl3__ in the header so i guess this is OpenGL 3.0. Is there a way to identify the versions? Sorry, i'm quite new.

Comment: `const GLubyte *v = glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION);
NSLog(@"GLSL version %s", v);`

Comment: @SAKrisT Thanks. Its version 1.20. Updated my question.

Answer (score 4):

You have already figured out how to solve your problem: just remove the line with the precision qualifier.

The bigger issue is that you haven't decided what version of OpenGL you are using. The GLSL sample you provided seems to be for an old version of the GLSL associated with OpenGL ***ES***, which is designed for mobile devices. Since you are actually running on a desktop/laptop, you want "normal" OpenGL. The error you observed is a result of the differences between the two.

In general you want to go with the latest version of OpenGL that is support by the systems you are targeting. Right now that is probably OpenGL 3.3 (along with GLSL 3.3).

Answer (score 2):

The `precision` keyword is a OpenGL/ES extension.  Since you have no `#version` in your vertex shader, you are getting GLSL v1.1 (backwards compatible with OpenGL2.0), which doesn't support such GL/ES extensions.

Either remove the `precision` line (which probably does nothing on desktop GL anyways), or add a `#version` for some version of GLSL that supports `precision`.

Comment: The shader which i am using is one from an OpenGL ES project. So is 'precision' keyword redundant on the desktop? Do i need to specify version for OpenGL GLSL?

Comment: @Alterecho Yes, it is redundant. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Precision qualifiers in OpenGL 3.3 are redundant. From the OpenGL 3.3 spec, "Precision qualifiers are added for code portability with OpenGL ES, **not for functionality**. They have the same syntax as in OpenGL ES, as described below, but they have **no semantic meaning**, which includes **no effect** on the precision used to store or operate on variables".

Use `#version 330 core` for strict 3.3 with no backward compatibility. And lose the precision qualifiers if you don't need ES compatibility.